# Removing the contains ads label from the google play store

Tags: unity, android, unity-ads

So previously in my Unity android game we had ads. Now I'm creating a demo version of the game from that project. I have succesfully removed all other permisions but the 'contains ads' still shows up on the google play store page. I have disabled the ads service from the services tab in the editor. I have comented or deleted all references to UnityEngine.Advertisements. Exporting the project to android studio results in this manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.LeadersPlay.LeadStreet" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.26" android:versionCode="45" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:name="com.LeadersPlay.LeadStreet.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="21447188-7121-4c3e-8f0e-6602ae1caa74" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Where I cant find a single reference to adverts. I have also waited for the new version to be refreshed in the store.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to remove the ads from you app it looks like to you need to update your ad settings in the Google Play Console.

This can be found (as of 2018) by selecting the App you want to modify and then selecting **Store presence -> Pricing & distribution** and setting **Contains ads** to no.

[image: Google Play Console Settings]